# Cliente para receber dados de um Server-Push

Tags: java, rest, push-notification

Estou tentado criar um cliente para consumir dados de uma interface a qual recebe dados de um gateway. 
Essa interface implementa um server-push que precisa ser iniciado a partir de uma requisição PUT feita pelo client. Depois da requisição retornar 200, a interface deveria começar a enviar os dados para o path **/rest/callback/payloads/ul** assim que os dados cheguem a ela.

Na requisição são enviados dados de registro da minha aplicação para que a interface direcione o push para a aplicação registrada, o arquivo *Requisicao.java* é o seguinte:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

json.addProperty("host", "http://myhost");
json.addProperty("port", 443);
json.addProperty("path_prefix", "/Omni/servlet");
json.addProperty("auth_string", "Basic " + "user:pass");
json.addProperty("retry_policy", 0);
json.addProperty("data_format", "base64");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json_string = gson.toJson(json);

URL url = new URL("https://server.orbiwise.com/rest/pushmode/start");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "user:pass");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(json_string);
out.close();

if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    System.out.println("SUCCESS!: " + conn.getResponseCode());
} else {
    System.out.println("ERROR: " + conn.getErrorStream() + conn.getResponseCode() );
}
```

A requisição já está retornando OK e para receber os dados do push eu utilizei um Servlet com path igual ao que a documentação da interface solicita (*/rest/callback/payloads/ul*). Porém os dados não estão chegando até ele. 
Se puderem me ajudar ou dar dicas de uma maneira mais simples de receber esses dados, agradeceria muito.